# Хочу поместить во внутрь строки переменную

Tags: python, строки, переменные

```
x = max(lst)
y = len(x)
lst0 = []
for i in lst:
    i0 = "{:_<y}".format(i)
    lst0.append(i0)
return lst0
```

хочу чтобы внутри заполнителя читалась переменная y

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что ты пытаешься сделать, но если ты хочешь подставить `y` то тебе в формат нужно передать именно `y` а не `i` и удали лишнее оттуда.
i0 = "{y}".format(y)

Comment: Я хочу поместить значение переменной y именно в таком виде внутрь заполнителя. Допустим y = 4, тогда мой код должен читаться в следующем виде:i0 = "{:_<4}".format(i)

Comment: как то так i0 = f":_<{y}"

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `f-строку`, только нужно экранировать ваши фигурные скобки, написав их как двойные:

```py
i0 = f"{{:_<{y}}}".format(i)
```